# How to Start Breathe app programmatically using another iWatch app?

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-watch

I am trying to create an iWatch app to read HRV values at a particular time period. For this I want my iWatch app to activate/Initiate the Breathe activity so that it is able to capture the HRV readings.

How can I activate the breathe activity programmatically from my iWatch app?
Please suggest if there is any  advice, links or guides to do so.Thank you

Comment: "activity" is a non-existent term in the iOS world, do you mean "app" or " view" or something else?

Comment: By activity i would like to start the Breathe app. For example If i want to start a workout session using my app, i could initiate that programmatically . 
Similarly, I want to start the breathe and get the readings. Do this make sense?